# WebApi 2.0 - No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, postman

With the code below I hit the constructor but never the action. The URL is 
http://localhost:64704/api/mytest/mymethod. Same problem when I tried to change the routing like this :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );

[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyTestController : ApiController
{
    readonly IMyFacade myFacade;
    public MyTestController(IMyFacade myFacade) => this.myFacade = myFacade;

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("mymethod")]
    public IHttpActionResult MyMethodName([FromBody]MyModel model)
    {
        //some code here

        return Ok();
    }
}

public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Update 1

```
public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
    }
}
```

Update 2

```
        public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();

        /* ...... */

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
```

Update 3
    {
    "Field1": "1",
    "Field2": "some key",
    "Field3": "some name of course"
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue occurs because you are expecting that the Route attribute ontop of the controller will be merge with the Route attribute ontop of the method.
This is not the case in .net [WebApi 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), (added in .net core mvc)

You should instead use the RoutePrefix attribute on the controller to make the controller route to be merged with the method routes

```
[RoutePrefix("api/[controller]")]
public class MyTestController : ApiController
{
    readonly IMyFacade myFacade;
    public MyTestController(IMyFacade myFacade) => this.myFacade = myFacade;

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("mymethod")]
    public IHttpActionResult MyMethodName([FromBody]MyModel model)
    {
        //some code here

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: I made your change but I don't hit. That's make me crazy :)

Comment: @Kris-I have you attached the webapiconfig to the httpconfiguration? Also, make sure you post the MyModel object correctly from the postman client.

Comment: @Kris-I make sure the unity resolver is attached to the GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver

Comment: @Kris-I ok, great. then the postman setup will be intresting, how do you compose the body

Comment: Even when post without argument and same.

Comment: @Kris-I if the model you post does not match the method model then the request may not reach the method at all. Also, try and move the webapiconfig in global.asax to the last line.

Comment: I remove the [controller] in RoutePrefix and that's work it's strange

Comment: @Kris-I Great find! totally missed that. Guess that feature was introduced in the .net core mvc release

Answer (score 1):

**WebApiConfig**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
 public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
 {
     protected void Application_Start()
     {
         AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
         GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
         FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
         RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
         BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
     }
 }
```

**Controller**

```
public class MyTestController : ApiController
{      
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("mymethod")]
    public IHttpActionResult MyMethodName([FromBody]MyModel model)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**While Debugging**

[image]

**Sending PostRequest**

[image]

Comment: some kind of explanation, e.g. "You need to add this" or "You have to change that" would certainly help to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In controller, you need to specify **RoutePrefix** attribute instead of **Route** as shown in below code

```
// Specify 'RoutePrefix' attribute instead of 'Route'
[RoutePrefix("api/[controller]")]
public class MyTestController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("mymethod")]
    public HttpResponseMessage MyMethodName([FromBody]MyModel model)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

and try again.

Answer (score -1):

You are using HttpPost verbs in action, make sure you use HttpPost method when sending request.

Comment: i saw that you are using Route attribute in controller make it to RoutePrefix("api/controller")

Comment: for more information regarding web api attribute routing refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2